# Is there a way to replace the "openwith" name for java apps in windows?

Tags: java, windows, shell, registry

i have a java app in windows, put in the registy the entries for the file extension and for the app.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.xxx -> (Default)=xxxApp, Content Type=..., PerceivedType=...

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.xxx/OpenWithProgIDs -> (Default)=xxxApp

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.xxx/ShellNew -> command=c:\\java... -jar xxxApp.jar  and  ItemName=xxxApp

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/xxxApp -> (Default)=xxxApp

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/xxxApp/shell/open/command -> (Default)=c:\\java... -jar xxxApp.jar
```

i have the right name in the tooltip and filetype, but in "open with" is java(tm).... how can i change the open with name?

Answer (score 0):

If your referring to the "open with" text when you right click, you cannot do this for an individual file. It is possible to change the text, but it will occur for all formats.

Answer (score 0):

I would go the way of creating a simple .exe file in C++ that would invoke java (and other stuff if you need, like checking the JVM version, etc.)